# Came up with this unusual error when trying to run my Xcode made app on my iPhone.

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm currently using the new Xcode-Beta as of the 30th July. I have been playing around and I found some Projects on GitHub that I have been looking at. I have been able to package them and then run them on my iPhone, however when I go to create my own project and run it, I receive this error message:

> No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the team ID “(null)” were found.

I'm not sure what the issue is, as I cannot run the app on the simulator or my iPhone

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Its because the people on Github posting their own apps have signed them with their apple developer account. You need an apple developer account to create signed applications. Its 100$ a year. https://developer.apple.com

Comment: I don't believe you do. On the new Xcode you can run Xcode apps on your IPhone. Also if you read what I have written, the simulator is not running the apps either